# Url rewriting not working in zend framework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am setting zend framework 2 project as per provided documentation in [Zend quick start](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/skeleton-application.html)

I have downloaded skeleton application, It displayed "welcome to zend framework" home page correctly. And as per suggested in documenation I have tried to access [myproject.localhost/1234](http://myproject.localhost/1234) url but it does not displayed 404 error within the project scope but 'Not found' page opened without navigation bar, css (ie. url rewritting not working). I do not have IIS installed on my machine only have wamp server, So idealy it should work.

Can anyone guide me for this error. I have created virtual host also

Comment: Have you checked that the domain myproject.localhost point to 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to resolve a **not-configured route** by requesting myproject.local/1234 so, if you want to pass 1234 as parameter to your index controller (home route), set that route begging from [this line](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php#L16) like follows:

```
'home' => array(
    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
    'options' => array(
    'route'    => '/[:myparam]',
    'constraints' => array(
        'id' => '\d*',
    ),
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
        'action'     => 'index',
        ),
    ),
),
```

Now you can get myparam in in IndexController something like this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $myparam = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('myparam', 0);
    var_dump($myparam); // Prints 123 on myproject.localhost/123 and 0 on myproject.localhost
    exit; // Exit for just simply show the logic. Don't use exit in controller like this.
}
```